# How to disable browser autocomplete on p-inputMask field?

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I'm trying to disable **browser autocomplete** on a field that uses **p-inputMask**. I can use **autocomplete="nope"** on any other field and it works great, but it doesn't seem to work on this special case. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing, please? Thanks a lot in advance!

**Please attached picture:**

Here's my code:

[**LIVE DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5rzzly?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

```
<p-inputMask autocomplete="nope" name="maskValue" mask="(999) 999-9999" placeholder="(999) 999-9999" ></p-inputMask>
```

**NOTE:**
You will see the browser autocomplete after entering a phone number and clicking on send. I'm trying to get rid of it, but I don't know how.

Comment: Did try on chrome, send button does not do anything and no auto complete as well. – Dipen Shah

Comment: @DipenShah I'm also using chrome and I'm able to reproduce it. See attached picture. You may also want to refresh the browser.

Comment: the sample you provided doesn't seem to exhibit the behavior you are describing on it's own.... are you *sure* you don't have some other extension installed that is causing this?

Comment: @Claies no extension. I'm just using primeng

Comment: definitely don't see the autocomplete box, tried chrome, firefox, and safari on two different computers.

Comment: @Claies I'm using the same Live Demo code I provided as well as Chrome and I can see it just like it's being shown in the picture. You may also want to click on send button and refresh your browser.

Comment: tried refreshing, tried copy paste, tried closing and reopening the browser.... and as I said, tried on two different computers.  and clearly I'm not the only one that can't reproduce this, since even another (now deleted answer) said as much as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`autocomplete="off"` can be used in the form, but it will disable autocomplete from the entire form.

```
<form autocomplete="off">
   <p-inputMask name="maskValue" mask="(999) 999-9999" placeholder="(999) 999-9999" ></p-inputMask>
   <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

[stackblitz here to disable autocomplete in entire form..](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mnzirz)

but since it disables autocomplete from the entire form, and if you want that to be done with the single `p-inputMask` you can use something like this, in a more generic way-

`setAttribute('autocomplete', 'off')` on `AfterViewInit` on specific fields.

[stackblitz to disable autocomplete only from inputmask](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vjzaq7)

Answer (score 1):

You're giving autocomplete attribute to primeng component.

When I check the primeng source code for p-inputmask I couldn't see an input field for autocomplete. It doesn't bind autcocomplete=off to html input element.

Here you can also check from [here](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/inputmask/inputmask.ts)

You can open an issue for it.

Also you can try this. Add autocomplete=off to form element

```
<form autocomplete="off">
   <p-inputMask name="maskValue" mask="(999) 999-9999" placeholder="(999) 999-9999" ></p-inputMask>
   <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add to the `autocomplete="off"`, `autocomplete="nope"` doesn't seem a correct value for the autocomplete attribute. That is the recommend way to disable autocomplete for a field.

This attribute can be added to the form to disable the autocomplete for all fields in the form.

[More info on W3s](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp)

Comment: Yes, I have tried autocomplete="off" but no success. Also autocomple="nope" is a valid option. Check this out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion

Comment: *technically*, `'nope'` really isn't a valid option, but the fact that it is definitely an invalid option triggers the autocomplete on most browsers to just stop trying.  you could use anything that was invalid, like `'idontwantthis'` and it should still break the browser implementation.  but just because that's something that mozilla documented doesn't mean it's a good practice.....