# PrimeNG p-inputNumber: prevent paste and autocomplete

Tags: angular, input, primeng

I am using PrimeNG11 and would like to turn off the autocomplete for a p-inputNumber control. Also, I would like to prevent paste-events for anything other than digits. The [autocomplete]="off" doesn't work. For the paste-event, I tried to catch the (onKeyDown)-event because there is no (onPaste) available for this control either. But it's not working the way I want it to. It fires when pressing ctrl, i.e. when the event code 'ControlLeft' is fired already. Does anyone has an idea on how to do this the right way?

Comment: Did you try creating an `EventListener` for the event `onpaste`, for the PrimeNG p-inputNumber component inside the `AfterViewInit` lifecycle hook?

Comment: No, I didn't. Figured there might be a better way maybe?

Comment: Since PrimeNG doesn't provide out-of-the-mill method to capture `onpaste` method, I think creating an `EventListener` for the event in question is the most appropriate way.

Comment: ok thanx, will have a look. How about preventing the autocomplete? Do you recommend the EventListener as well for that case?

Comment: Did `autocomplete="off"` work?

Comment: Hi, I did it via the AfterViewInit as described in the accepted answer of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53601587/how-to-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-p-inputmask-field and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I did it via the AfterViewInit as described in the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53601587/how-to-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-p-inputmask-field) and it worked.